# Can Visual Studio Community 2013 create SharePoint projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, prerequisites

I have installed SharePoint 2013 Enterprise and Visual Studio 2013 Community.

How do I create SharePoint projects? “New Project” shows many templates, but not the ones related to SharePoint.

Do I need Visual Studio Professional for SharePoint development (I mean development of .wsp solutions)?

Comment: For the new coming visitors, check how you can install office developer tools for [**Visual Studio 2017**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-sharepoint-template-in-vs2017/) & [**Visual Studio 2015**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/office-sharepoint-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2015/) & [**Visual Studio Community 2013**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-officesharepoint-template-in-visual-studio-community-2013/)

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP thx!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, VS Community 2013 (and 2015) supports creating SharePoint solutions and apps.

I am working through some provider hosted app examples in it right now.

The templates should be under C#(or VB) -> Office/SharePoint -- if you don't see them you may not have the Office Developer tools installed -- you can find them here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx

Comment: (I assume that sharepoint installed locally is still required for .wsp)

Comment: A local SharePoint Server install is still required if you want to develop SharePoint solutions (farm and sandbox solutions) -- you can develop Apps without a local SharePoint install.

Comment: The thing is that Office (& SharePoint) tools don't seem to be part of standard installation, and even if you choose 'Repair installation' that option isn't there to be added. It's really required to download and install manually from the link provided above, or via Web Platform Installer