# Sharepoint Templates missing in Visual studio 2013 Express edition

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

I have installed Visual studio 2013 express edition. But there are no SharePoint Templates available. While i am going to installing office developer tool for visual studio 2013 then it show massage,

"You must install Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Professional Edition or above"

Is it does not support SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Visual Studio Express supports the Office Developer tools

You might be better off installing the free Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition though.

https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

Comment: Ohk..But are you sure that Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition supports Office Developer tools OR SharePoint templates?

Comment: It sure does! I download the developer tools via the web platform installer, just by going here https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx

Comment: Here's another question on the topic http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123325/can-visual-studio-community-2013-create-sharepoint-projects?rq=1